# Which sorting technique is the below code?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

Below is a javascript code for sorting an array with n numbers in ascending order. I have used this code in few interviews but was unable to figure out which sorting technique is this.

```
let arr = [7, 9, 2, 11, 5]

for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  for (let j = i + 1; j < arr.length; j++) {
    if (arr[j] < arr[i]) {
      let temp = arr[i]
      arr[i] = arr[j]
      arr[j] = temp
    }
  }
}

console.log(arr)   //[2, 5, 7, 9, 11]
```

Comment: It's [exchange sort](https://www.codingunit.com/exchange-sort-algorithm).

Answer (score -1):

This sorting techinque is called Selection sort and it has a Space Complexity of O(n)
and the logic behind this code is find the minimum element in unsorted array and swap it with the element at beginning of unsorted array.Like wise they are many sorting techinque too like insertion sort,bubble sort and many more.

Feel free to ask anything if you find any trouble :)